# Localhost not working with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express, pug

Following is a small server (app.js) which is is simply calling index.jade file to add jquery.js, underscore.js and backbone.js for later use. 
But its not working. 
My directory structure is:

```
 base
    app.js
    public
          jquery.js
          underscore.js
          backbone.js
          theapp.js
    views
          index.jade
```

My app.js file is:

```
var express= require("express"),
    http   = require("http"),
    path   = require("path");

var app= express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname+ "/public"));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("views/index.jade");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

My index.jade file is:

```
#main

script(src= "jquery.js")
script(src= "underscore.js")
script(src= "backbone.js")
script(src= "theapp.js")
```

When I run localhost:3000 in the browser, it says: Error: Failed to lookup view "views/index.jade"

(Localhost is working fine with another node.js program)

Please help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont include the `.jade`

```
res.render("views/index");
```

Assuming your view engine is already setup to use Jade. (`app.set('view engine', 'jade');`)

You also probably dont need to specify the "views" folder, check for the line

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

in your app.js - this is the root directory for your views, so you'll only need:

```
res.render("index");
```

Comment: Still the same error: Error: Failed to lookup view "views/index"

Comment: Did not work, network tab in chrome console shows files pending!